# Meaning of 「がです」

Tags: grammar, particle-が

I found this sentence in a story I'm reading:

> 誰にだって、どんな人にだって一度くらいはそういうことがあるんじゃないかと思います。理屈抜きで誰か嫌いになること**がです**

Trying to understand 「がです」 I tried looking on Google, on my grammars and here on Stack Exchange, but I only found the reverse order, 「ですが」; Google translate translate it as "is", but Google translations aren't alway that great, especially with single words.

I think can understand the sentence ("No matter who, no matter which type of person, I think everyone does it at least once, isn't it? To hate someone without reason"), but I can't wrap my head around 「がです」. I don't think it nominalize the preceding sentences, both because I'm not even sure 「が」 can do such a thing (I don't think I ever saw it used that way; on the contrary, when nominalization is needed, 「のが」, with 「の」 to nominalize), and there is already 「こと」 doing the nominalization.

Is that the 「が」particle? What does it means in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「誰{だれ}にだって、どんな人にだって一度{いちど}くらいは**そういうこと**があるんじゃないかと思{おも}います。理屈抜{りくつぬ}きで誰か嫌{きら}いになること**がです**。」

As always, the answer (or at least a big hint) can be found in the context.  Here, the answer is right there in the first sentence.

「そういう**こと**」＝「理屈抜きで誰か嫌いになる**こと**」

Though I am certain that what 「そういうこと」 roughly refers to has already been explained even prior to the first sentence, it is explained once again (perhaps in more concrete and/or concise terms) in the second sentence.

「がです」 has nothing to do with 「ですが」 and it is used far more often than you seem to think.  The 「が」 in 「がです」 is, of course, a particle.  It is the regular subject-marker preceded by the noun 「こと」.

**Point is, however, something is left unsaid between the 「が」 and 「です」** because it gets wordy and awkward if it is said.

「理屈抜きで誰か嫌いになること**がです**」

＝「理屈抜きで誰か嫌いになること**が**（あるんじゃないかと思うの）**です**」

「あるんじゃないかと思います」 has already been said in the first sentence, so why repeat it in the second?

Hand-made examples:

A:「じゃあ、小学校{しょうがっこう}は大阪{おおさか}**で**卒業{そつぎょう}したん**です**ね？」

B:「いいえ、青森{あおもり}**でです**。」

A:「今日{きょう}はお父{とう}さん**と**来{き}たん**です**ね？」

B:「いいえ、母{はは}**とです**。」

A:「足{あし}**が**かゆいん**です**か？」

B:「いいえ、背中{せなか}**がです**。」

て、なんちゅうコントやねん！